# Query items from list between Time ranges

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

I am trying to view all items on time between 08:00 to 17:00, I get only one item count even if I have more?

```
var fromTime = new Date(result);
            fromTime.setHours(8);
            var toTime = new Date(result2);
            toTime.setHours(17);
            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'EventDate\'><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>' + fromTime.toISOString() + '</Value><FieldRef Name=\'EndDate\' /></Geq><Leq><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>' + toTime.toISOString() + '</Value></Leq></And></Where></Query></View>');


            this.collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
            context.load(collListItem);

            var itemCount = collListItem.get_count();
            if (itemCount > 0) {
                alert(itemCount);
            }
```

item count gets only 1 when i have 2 items in the list why?

Comment: Martin, you can show me the values of these items in the list?
 Item 1: EventDate, EndDate.
 Item 2: EventDate, EndDate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry, did not understand your question and noticed your code, you want to pick up items filtering EventDate and EndDate?

What is the value of fromTime.setTime() and toTime.setHours(17)?

trying to answer your question:

the format example: date to filter between 2014-12-02T**08**:00:00Z and 2014-12-02T**17**:00:00Z

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='date' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2014-12-02T08:00:00Z</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='date' /><Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2014-12-02T17:00:00Z</Value></Leq></And></Where></Query></View>");
```

> before using this code checks FieldRef Name = **'date'**.

I had search and test setHours(8 or 17) not work perfectly with toISOString() see [the documentation here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp), Unfortunate not is possible, but i have logic for resolve this question.

**Update(2):**

```
var fromTime = new Date(result);
var fromtimeConverted = fromTime.toJSON().split('T')[0] + "T08:00:00Z";  //fromTime.setHours(8);
var toTime = new Date(result2);
var toTimeConverted = toTime.toJSON().split('T')[0] + "T17:00:00Z";//toTime.setHours(17);
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'EventDate\'><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>' + fromtimeConverted + '</Value><FieldRef Name=\'EndDate\' /></Geq><Leq><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>' + toTimeConverted + '</Value></Leq></And></Where></Query></View>');


this.collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
context.load(collListItem);

var itemCount = collListItem.get_count();
if (itemCount > 0) {
    alert(itemCount);
}
```

Comment: fromTime and toTime is current date and time from the users input i am trying to user current date from the user add set his time to 8-17 alock, how could i use in the query fromTime.setHours(8) and toTime.setHours(17) together with toISOString() =?

Comment: yes, you can convert this date to format **YYYY-MM-DDTHH-MM-SSZ** ?

Comment: Yes i know, but how do i do that using the things a asked in the question abow?

Comment: Ok i will help you, pls wait, i will edit answer here.

Comment: Alright i only get the current added item and not all items from that date and range

Comment: what is value of itemCount?

Comment: i have two items in the list but the count show only 1. its not working only 1

Comment: try again with new code Martin

Comment: i still get only count 1? @b1c10

Comment: is still returning one item? i has tested code here(that has create for resolve this question), and work fine.

Comment: i have med in to work, was some other problem

Comment: what is other problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong. Try this

```
'<View><Query><Where><And><Gt><FieldRef Name=\'EventDate\' /><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>' + fromTime.setTime() + '</Value><Gt><Lt><FieldRef Name=\'EndDate\' /><Value IncludeTimeValue=\'TRUE\' Type=\'DateTime\'>' + toTime.setHours(17) + '</Value></Lt></And></Where></Query></View>'
```

Comment: I have tried with that also i only get current added item and not all items between the ranges

Comment: i think maybe i need to use toISOString() how do i user that togher with setHours()?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure your query is wrong, you are missing the where and query tag into it
check this documentation:
[Retrieve List Items Using JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: I have already tried with and without i only get current added item